# Error while attempting to synchronize system time

Tags: 12.04, time, clock

I recently noticed that the time on my system clock is off by several minutes. Currently, my date and time settings say that the time is being set "Automatically from the Internet".

That doesn't seem to be working, so I looked around for a way to sync the time on my system manually. After a bit of Googling, I discovered the ntpdate command. Unfortunately, this command seems to be erroring out:

```
$ sudo ntpdate -d pool.ntp.org 
 7 Jan 08:28:11 ntpdate[3489]: ntpdate 4.2.6p3@1.2290-o Tue Jun  5 20:12:12 UTC 2012 (1)
Looking for host pool.ntp.org and service ntp
host found : ns20.alltraders.com
transmit(173.230.149.23)
transmit(149.20.68.17)
transmit(209.118.204.201)
transmit(64.251.10.152)
transmit(173.230.149.23)
transmit(149.20.68.17)
transmit(209.118.204.201)
transmit(64.251.10.152)
transmit(173.230.149.23)
transmit(149.20.68.17)
transmit(209.118.204.201)
transmit(64.251.10.152)
transmit(173.230.149.23)
transmit(149.20.68.17)
transmit(209.118.204.201)
transmit(64.251.10.152)
transmit(173.230.149.23)
transmit(149.20.68.17)
transmit(209.118.204.201)
transmit(64.251.10.152)
173.230.149.23: Server dropped: no data
149.20.68.17: Server dropped: no data
209.118.204.201: Server dropped: no data
64.251.10.152: Server dropped: no data
server 173.230.149.23, port 123
stratum 0, precision 0, leap 00, trust 000
refid [173.230.149.23], delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  0:28:16.000
originate timestamp: 00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  0:28:16.000
transmit timestamp:  d6768d81.5b4dd22c  Tue, Jan  7 2014  8:28:17.356
filter delay:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
offset 0.000000

server 149.20.68.17, port 123
stratum 0, precision 0, leap 00, trust 000
refid [149.20.68.17], delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  0:28:16.000
originate timestamp: 00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  0:28:16.000
transmit timestamp:  d6768d81.8e81c0d2  Tue, Jan  7 2014  8:28:17.556
filter delay:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
offset 0.000000

server 209.118.204.201, port 123
stratum 0, precision 0, leap 00, trust 000
refid [209.118.204.201], delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  0:28:16.000
originate timestamp: 00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  0:28:16.000
transmit timestamp:  d6768d81.c1b350c2  Tue, Jan  7 2014  8:28:17.756
filter delay:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
offset 0.000000

server 64.251.10.152, port 123
stratum 0, precision 0, leap 00, trust 000
refid [64.251.10.152], delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  0:28:16.000
originate timestamp: 00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  0:28:16.000
transmit timestamp:  d6768d81.f4e76850  Tue, Jan  7 2014  8:28:17.956
filter delay:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
offset 0.000000

 7 Jan 08:28:19 ntpdate[3489]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

I'm confused. What's wrong here? It seems to me that it found plenty of servers, so why can't it sync with them? I'm behind a proxy, could that have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with another server like ntp.ubuntu.com instead of pool.ntp.org?

Comment: Yes, with very similar results: http://dumptext.com/qtqAWiBk/raw/